# Define and return a function from a function?

Tags: c++, function

How does one define and return a function inside a function?

For instance, we have a function like:

```
float foo(float val) {return val * val;}
```

Now, what is needed is a function like bar:

```
typedef float (*func_t)(float)
// Rubish pseudo code
func_t bar(float coeff) {return coeff * foo();}
// Real intention, create a function that returns a variant of foo
//  that is multiplied by coeff. h(x) = coeff * foo(x)
```

The only thing I've came up with so far is using lambda or a class. Is there a straight forward way to do this without being convoluted needlessly?

Comment: Do you mean `typedef float (*func_t)(float);`? (Notice the star *before* func_t, not *after*) Like: define func_t as a pointer to function that takes float and returns float?

Comment: @NathanOliver It says rubbish pseudo code in the comment. Pretty sure the intention is clear to anyone but a human compiler. Added another comment just in case.

Comment: @FabioTurati Yeah, that was a mistype.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I kinda rushed it. Thanks for the comment. :D

Comment: There isn't a way to do it without using a lambda or a class — and I'm not sure how much of what you want to do can be done with them.  Lambdas were added in part to allow machinations along the lines you're after.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I meant lambda like Basile suggested. Objected it at first but the example code is very concise and noob friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (with `std::function`) -using [lambda functions](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)- in C++11 are appropriate and recommended here. So have

```
std::function<int(int)> translate (int delta) { 
   return [delta](int x) {return x+delta;} }
```

then you might later code:

```
 auto t3 = translate(3);
```

Now `t3` is the "function" which adds 3, later:

```
 int y = t3(2), z = t3(5);
```

and of course have `y` be 5 and `z` be 8.

You could also use some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library to generate machine code on the fly, e.g. [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), or [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit); or you could even  generate some C++ (or C) code in some generated file `/tmp/mygencod.cc` and fork a compilation of that (e.g. `g++ -Wall -O -fPIC /tmp/mygencod.cc -shared -o /tmp/mygencod.so`) into a `/tmp/mygencod.so` [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) then [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that plugin using [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) on POSIX systems (and later [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) to get a function pointer from a name; beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for C++). I am doing such things in [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Comment: If that is the only valid option, could you give a quick example doing what is intended in the question or something in the veins of that? Such as g(f, y) returns h where h(x) = f(x) + y;

Comment: I like that it's more concise. wp

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/)

```
std::function<float(float)> bar(float coeff)
{
    auto f = [coeff](float x)
    {
        return coeff * foo(x);
    };

    return f;
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
auto f = bar(coeff);
auto result = f(x);
```

Comment: What parameters does f accepts exactly? What is the return value?

Comment: @zehelvion In this case f is a function that accepts no parameters and does not return a value.

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate on how to apply this to something in the veins of my question?

Comment: How would you define g(f, y) that returns h where h(x) = f(x) + y;

Comment: @MohamadElghawi You had the parameter coeff at the wrong function, I hope you don't mind my edit. By the way, you don't need to store `f` as a variable; you can return it directly.

Comment: @leemes Thanks! I guess you could pass both floats into f but that's completely up to you. And yes I know you can return it directly I guess I wanted to show a) a function being defined in another and b) returning said function.

Comment: hmm, I think foo should be passed in as an argument in your example (see my edit)

Comment: @zehelvion Well it depends. Maybe foo is a a global function somewhere or a member function of the same class. If you do want to pass it in then I would suggest sticking to std::function.

Comment: @zehelvion If you want to pass foo also, you need to put it in the "capture-list" in order to use it in the lambda (to copy the value into the lambda to be available when the lambda is being called): `[coeff,foo]`

Comment: Oops, wrong link, sorry. I meant to link @zehelvion.